How to format a LaTeX input file to adapt equations for different layouts in multiple documents?
tldr:
I have a shared LaTeX input file containing a long equation (./theorem.tex). When included in a wide single-column document (notes.tex), the equation displays properly in one line. However, in a narrower multi-column layout (cheatsheet.tex), the equation overflows into the next column. How can I modify the shared input file to ensure the equation fits neatly in the cheatsheet (e.g., with line breaks) while still displaying in a single line in the notes?

I'm trying to compile a cheatsheet and a set of notes from the same input file.
Specifically, my input file look something like this:
\section{Some fancy theorem}

This is a fancy theorem:
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-x^{n}\right)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{k\left(3k-1\right)/2}=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\left(x^{k(3k+1)/2}+x^{k(3k-1)/2}\right).
\end{equation*}

Suppose the file above is ./theorem.tex.
Now we have two sets of files:
notes.tex, which looks like:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}

\title{\textbf{Notes}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\input{./theorem.tex}

\end{document}

and cheatsheet.tex which has the form:
\documentclass[11pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{center}
     \Large{\textbf{Cheatsheet}} \\
\end{center}

\input{./theorem.tex}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}

As cheatsheet.tex has 3 columns, the long equation doesn't fit into a single column and spills into the next one. On the other hand, it displays correctly in notes.tex as there is a wider space for it to fit.
Is it possible to modify the input file (./theorem.tex) in a way that the equation will fit within the column for cheatsheet.tex (i.e with a line break (or two) somewhere within) and also display in a single line in notes.tex.
Ideally I want a single input file so that I can compile both the cheatsheet and notes simultaneously.

note size commands do not take an argument, \Large{..} should be \Large ... for teh main question it is best to put the equation in two forms with suitable line breaking for each textwidth

How can I put the equation in two forms whilst maintaining a single input file for both documents?

lots of ways: there are packages or simply put \newif\ifcheat   and either \cheattrue or \cheatfalse in the preamble  then have \ifcheat \begin{align} lots\\of\\short\\lines\end{align} \else $all fits on one line$ \fi

Off-topic: it's not necessary to load amsfonts and amsmath explicitly as the former package is loaded automatically by amssymb and the latter is loaded automatically by mathtools.

As @DavidCarlisle has already pointed out in a comment, there are lots of ways to achieve your formatting objective. The following suggestions are thus but a few of many possibilities.
First, two versions of file theorem.tex. The first version employs a single multline* environment to cover both layouts; the second employs the same multline* solution for the three-column case, and an equation* environment for the one-column case. In both versions, note the use of an \ifdim conditional to differentiate the output depending on which layout is in use.
\section{Some fancy theorem}

This is a fancy equation:
\begin{multline*}
  \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-x^n)
  =\sum_{\mathclap{k=-\infty}}^{\infty}
  (-1)^k x^{k(3k-1)/2}
  \ifdim \columnwidth<\textwidth \\ \fi % note the use of '\ifdim'
  = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k
  \bigl( x^{k(3k+1)/2}+x^{k(3k-1)/2} \bigr)\,.
\end{multline*}


\section{Some fancy theorem}

This is a fancy equation:
\ifdim \columnwidth<\textwidth % multiple-column mode
\begin{multline*}
  \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-x^n)
  =\sum_{\mathclap{k=-\infty}}^{\infty}
  (-1)^k x^{k(3k-1)/2} \\
  = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k
  \bigl( x^{k(3k+1)/2}+x^{k(3k-1)/2} \bigr)\,.
  \end{multline*}
\else % single-column mode
\begin{equation*}
  \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-x^n)
  =\sum_{\mathclap{k=-\infty}}^{\infty}
  (-1)^k x^{k(3k-1)/2} 
  = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k
  \bigl( x^{k(3k+1)/2}+x^{k(3k-1)/2} \bigr)\,.
  \end{equation*}
\fi

Do note, by the way, that I've gotten rid of all \left and \right auto-sizing directives that were in the OP's formulation of the equation. Why? It's either because \left and \right do nothing useful at all, as for instance in the cases of \left(-1\right) and \left(3k-1\right), while producing code clutter, or because they produce delimiters/"fences" that are needlessly large, as in the case of \left( x^{k(3k+1)/2} + x^{k(3k-1)/2} \right). There, I've switched to \bigl( x^{k(3k+1)/2} + x^{k(3k-1)/2} \bigr).
For more information on the topic of when not to use \left and \right, please see the posting Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?. Bottom line: Don't over-use \left and \right -- there is a real typographical downside to the over-use.

Next, notes.tex:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb, lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{\bfseries Notes}
\date{}
%\maketitle

\input theorem
\lipsum[1-3] % filler text

\end{document}


Finally, cheatsheet.tex:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[landscape,a4paper,margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb, lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
{\noindent\huge\bfseries Cheatsheet\par}
\input theorem
\lipsum[1-5] % filler text
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}


The first few lines of notes.pdf, using the second solution approach (separate equation* environment):

The first few lines of cheatsheet.pdf:


The multline environment causes my equations in the notes.tex file to be stretched out over the whole line, whereas in an equation env, the equation is centered and unstretched. Is there any work-around for this?
The stretching can also be seen in the screenshot that you attached.

@Apollonius - Please see the update I applied to my answer.

Perfect, thanks!
